# ASP.NET + Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a class in my App_Code directory that I'm trying to initialize from the root directory of my solution but it is not showing up in IntelliSense. I have tried changing the class's build action from Content to Compile but then IntelliSense throws a whole bunch of errors about not finding my DBML class.

**Note** DBML file, Class and aspx file are all in the same namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq;
```

^ Imports on class that I'm trying to initialize. (May be irrelevant)

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there build errors if you attempt to build? There might be an error with the class itself that isn't displaying in intellisense.

Comment: You need to make sure that “Build Action” of none of the files in the App_Code folder is marked as “Compile”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that Build Action of none of the files in the App_Code folder is marked as Compile.

> But this will bring its own side effects that intellisense may not
>   work very well for these files inside VS as they will not be treated
>   as Class files by VS… But the key point is that you do not really need
>   “App_Code in Web Application Projects (WAP) if you do not intend to
>   put random code files or modify existing code files in App_Code folder
>   directly on your production server…

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.fi/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Comment: Thats interesting because most places I read App_Code is the place for classes etc. Thanks for your input.